# Running a foreign Jupyter notebook - what can happen

Tags: security, jupyter-notebook

I read the security page from https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html , but that basically seems to say that you can secure your server, but that once you execute a notebook from someone else, the only thing protecting you is your decision not to execute code - which to me seems to be the major point of those notebooks.

Is it really the case that i am effectively granting whatever level of access to my whole system by executing code from a notebook - or is there a built-in way to sandbox this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running foreign jupyter notebooks does actually provide the risk of changes on your computer being made; for example delete files or change system settings.
This is especially easy since in built-in line magic commands are supported.

Even though all changes can be reversed (*with more or less effort*), the best way for you to secure yourself from unwanted changes is reading (*and understanding*) the code that you will execute.
This is actually not only a recommendation for notebooks specifically, but for all forms of code found online.

Comment: Network access and producing or altering files are also possible, i guess? (deleting files and altering system settings seems more like vandalism, while network and file creation could be used for-profit (and are thus more likely, imo)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know about network access (but I think so).  
Producing and altering files is easily doable and therefore a possible threat, yes.